# Send an image accessed from URI to a Server

Tags: android, kotlin, file, server

I'm able to retrieve an URI's image from my android gallery and then display it inside an `AsyncImage` using coil library.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        setContent {
            var selectedImageUri by remember { mutableStateOf<Uri?>(null) }

            val singlePhotoPikerLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
                contract = ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia(),
                onResult = { uri -> selectedImageUri = uri}
            )

            RandomAnimalClientTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Column (
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .padding(32.dp)
                ){

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

                    Button(onClick = {
                        singlePhotoPikerLauncher.launch(
                            PickVisualMediaRequest(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly)
                        )
                        Log.d("URI", selectedImageUri.toString())
                    }) {
                        Text(text="Create new animal")
                    }

                    AsyncImage(model = selectedImageUri, contentDescription = null )


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can also send a multipart request to my server like this :

```
val viewModel: MainViewModel = hiltViewModel()

Button(onClick = {
         if(selectedImageUri!=null){
             val file = File(cacheDir, "myImage.jpg")
             file.createNewFile()
             file.outputStream().use{ assets.open("cat.jpg").copyTo(it) }
             viewModel.sendNewAnimal(
                   animalName = "cat",
                   animalDesc = "a cute mammal",
                   animalImage = file
                   )
             }
       }
) {
        Text(text="send new animal")
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to send a file from outside the application, from the gallery for example. As I showed you earlier, I can only access the URI.

I already tried to convert URI to actual `File` object like this :

```
val file = File(selectedImageUri.path)
```

OR

```
val file = selectedImageUri.toFile()
```

But I get errors.

How could I do?

Comment: `The problem is that I don't know how to send a file from outside the application` What do you mean with 'outside the application'? If you have a path for a file and read access you can upload the file. If you have an uri for a file and read access you can upload that file.

Comment: Images in the gallery are not part of the application, so they are 'outside the application'. When I use selectedImageUri.toFile() I get this error : E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.tmcoding.randomanimal_client, PID: 28621
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Uri lacks 'file' scheme: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A59
        at androidx.core.net.UriKt.toFile(Uri.kt:43)

Comment: Also, by using File(selectedImageUri.path) I have this error : W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/image:63: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/07/05/multipart-upload-okttp-uri.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)`